# Causes for non-failing failing java assertions

Tags: java, debugging, error-handling, exception

What can be a reason

```
assert(false); //this should fail but doesn't

//this gets executed but shouldn't
if(!false) throw new IllegalStateException("what's the bloody point?!!");
```

throws the `IllegalStateException` rather than the `AssertionError`?

And yes, I have these two lines in the code just like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assertions are disabled by default at runtime, you need to provide either the -ea or -enableassertions JVM flag

[Enable assertions](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/java-keyword-assert)

Answer (score 1):

The only plausible answer is that you're executing without assertions on.

Assertions are disabled by default.

You need to parametrize the JVM with `-ea` when executing.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html).